# What do we iterate through when using pointer to an array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

This is a simple function for finding occurrences of a specific letter.

```
1:  int count_x(char *p, char a)
2:  {
3:      int count = 0;
4:      while(*p != '\0')
5:      {
6:        if (*p == a)
7:            count++;
8:        p++;
9:      }
10:      return count;
11:  }
```

We can get access to a specific element by using `p[n]`, or we can dereference it `*p` and get a first element of that array as an example, and all of that stuff we usually do.
The strange thing to me is located at the line number 8.
When we write `p++`, we are getting the array we passed -1 symbol from the beginning. So if it was `hello, world` then it would be `ello, world`.
We are somehow iterating throuhg the indices but i don't really understand how.

Can i have an explanation of how all of that stuff works?

Comment: ***we are getting the array we passed -1 symbol from the beginning.*** What does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop condition `*p != '\0'` means: *iterate until the value pointed by `p` is `'\0'`. The statement inside the loop body

```
p++;
```

increments the pointer to next character of the string passed.

For first iteration

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--- ----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |
|  'h'   |  'e'   |  'l'   |  'l'   |  'o'   |  ','   |  'w'   |  'o'   |  'r'   |  'l'   |  'd'   |  '\0'  |
|        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
  ^
  |       
  p
```

Second iteration :

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--- ----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |
|  'h'   |  'e'   |  'l'   |  'l'   |  'o'   |  ','   |  'w'   |  'o'   |  'r'   |  'l'   |  'd'   |  '\0'  |
|        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
             ^
             | 
             p
```

and so on. When `p` comes to point `'\0'`, condition `*p != '\0'` becomes `false` and loop terminates.
On every iteration it is the pointer `p` which changes the location where it points. String remain at its initial stored location.

Answer (score 1):

TL:DR - Using a pointer to the array, we iterate through the individual elements, just the same as we do using array indexing.

---

When you pass an array to a function, it decays to the pointer to the first element. So, `char *p` points to the first element in the array.

In this case, the function expects a null-terminated `char` array (or, pointer to the first element of a null-terminated `char` array) as the first argument.

Once you increment `p`, it points to the next element. That's why, if you try to print the incoming *string*, (actually `"hello, world"`), it now prints `"ello, world"`.

Also, by checking `*p != '\0'` you're making sure you don't go past the array (null-terminated).

Comment: ok, so what's wrong with this answer, please?

Comment: In my opinion it is a correct answer and I have up-voted it.

Comment: Once you increment p, it points to the next element.

Yeah, i got it. My point was to firure out how exactly all of that works?
When we're saying p++, what exactly do we increment?

Comment: @Caleb we increment the pointer. a pointer is an address pointing to some _object_. Now, once that _object_ is an array, it's elements are in contiguous memory locations. So, when we increment the pointer, it points to the address of the next element.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Appreciate it, sir. However, I was more  interested in getting a comment from the downvoter. At times, this hit-and-run DVs are quite frustrating.... _sigh_ ...

Comment: @SouravGhosh; These are the *ghost souls* buddy. No one can catch them :\

Answer (score 0):

Expression `s[i]` (where s is a character array) is evaluated the following way: s is converted to pointer to its first element and the so-called pointer arithmetic is applied. Then the result pointer is dereferenced.

So you can imaging `s[i]` the following way

```
char *p = s;
int i = 0;
p = p + i;
//...
if ( *p == a ) count++;
```

To get the next character you could write

```
++i;
p = p + i;
//..
```

However this is equivalent to

```
++p;
p = p + i;
```

where `i` has its previous value.

So you can increase either the index of the pointer. Now just assume that `i` is always equal to 0.

Then you can write

```
char *p = s;
int i = 0;
p = p + i;
//...
if ( *p == a ) count++;
++p;
p = p + 0;
if ( *p == a ) count++;
// and so on
```